# Combine options in one button or create separate buttons?

Tags: usability, gui-design, buttons

I'm redesigning iTunes and in this program "create playlist" action is hidden. You have to right click on "Music Playlists" to get a dialog of available options like "New playlist", "New Smart Playlist", "New Playlist Folder". Hiding an essential user action is a bad UX so I decided to make visible button for that. Creating one button would make interface less cluttered but there will be more clicks to finish the action.

**Which solution would have better usability?**

Also "New Smart Playlist" has an additional dialog with options to create it and in original iTunes UI it has three dots indicating pop up dialog like "New Smart Playlist..."

**Can I design a button without those three dots or would it make UX worse?**

Here is my first option:

[image: First]

Here is my second option:

[image: Second]

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question on "..." there is a topic on it already: [Usage of ellipses "..." on buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106793/usage-of-ellipses-on-buttons)
There it is said to use ellipsis when after pressing the button an additional input (e.g. opens a dialog) is required to proceed.

In my opinion splitting the functionality of the button is of added value if some of the new actions can go without a dialog, e.g. one simply presses on "Smart playlist" and that's all - the created playlist (even empty, but preferably with at least one item) can be edited later.

For creating a folder, why not place a textbox where user enters the folder name before clicking on "Create folder" button?

Comment: I don't want to place a textbox because the solution iTunes has right now is better: it already displays a folder where it's created and has "untitled folder" title selected to edit it or just press enter and create a folder with that name. Thus, user knows if he makes folder name too long, because folder is located inside sidebar. Secondly, user sees where folder was created.